# vim - why will search find it but search and replace not? (this escaped special char pattern)

Tags: linux, vim

want to search and replace in vim, the /find finds the pattern but :s%//g will not?

have a script that monitors software raid (if interested check it out https://dwaves.org/2019/09/06/linux-server-monitor-software-raid-mail-notification-on-failure/)

```
echo "=== smart status of all drives ==="| tee -a /scripts/monitor/raid_status_mail.log

# want to search and replace the /path/to/file.sh with $LOGFILE

# searching for the pattern works like charm
/\/scripts\/monitor\/raid_status_mail.log

# but replacing it won't
:s%/\/scripts\/monitor\/raid_status_mail\.log/\$LOGFILE/g

# what does one do wrong?
```

should replace /scripts/monitor/raid_status_mail.log with $LOGFILE

Answer (score 3):

The substitution operation needs to be prefixed with `%s` and not the other way around as `s%`. So doing

```
%s/\/scripts\/monitor\/raid_status_mail\.log/\$LOGFILE/g
```

should work as expected. Or just the Vim's equivalent `ex` in command line mode as

```
printf '%s\n' "%s/\/scripts\/monitor\/raid_status_mail\.log/\$LOGFILE/g" w q | ex -s file
```

Answer (score 2):

You inverted the beginning `s%`. Use `%s` instead.

Also, you use `/` as separation for the different fields, it works but makes the command less readable. You can replace the separation character by anything else. You could use `:` for example:

```
%s:/scripts/monitor/raid_status_mail.log:$LOGFILE:g
```

One last tip: install [vim-over](https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-over)

This will highlight your searches in live while replacing something in vim.